# How do I make a custom file extension open my java program?

Tags: java, file-extension

what I'm asking is how to make any associated file type open my program with the corresponding data. For example, if you have a .doc file it opens Microsoft word with whatever is saved to that file. I know how to associate the file extension to my program, but it just opens the program from the location of the file. How do I make the program read the file upon start-up?

Answer (score 5):

You make the program accept command-line arguments. When you open something from Explorer, it passes the name(s) of the item(s) you clicked on as command-line arguments. Your program must take these command-line arguments and do whatever processing is required... including opening and reading the contents.

In C/C++, these are the `argc` and `argv` arguments in `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. In Java, it's the args in `public static void main(String[] args)`. In other languages, you'll have to look into it.

Comment: So I start my method using my file loading method where args[0] is the name if the file?

Comment: One more thing, when I open the program with an associated file type, I get a dialog error window titled "Java Virtual Machine Launcher" and it says "A Java Exception has occurred." Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is Java and a desktop app., the obvious solution would be [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

> JWS provides many appealing features including, but not limited to, splash screens, desktop integration, **file associations,** automatic update (including lazy downloads and programmatic control of updates), partitioning of natives & other resource downloads by platform, architecture or Java version, configuration of run-time environment (minimum J2SE version, run-time options, RAM etc.), easy management of common resources using extensions..

Here is a [demo. of the file services](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs) that associates the type `.zzz` with the demo.  Double click such a file and it will open in the app.